# How to create event in admin's app caledar using Microsoft graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a calendar event using Microsoft Graph with the app's admin username and password. Actually, my logged-in user does not have access rights to edit that calendar.

They only need to, by clicking the button in my app, perform flow that will send admin's username and password using for example Basic Auth without using token and get permission to create calendar event using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar ID}/events
```

Is it possible to use Microsoft Graph without using tokens and Bearer Auth?

I want the user (with some action from my app) to produce a flow in which the app with the admin's credentials access the admin's calendar. Users only need to click the button. The user is just someone who starts the flow.

Comment: If you're using Microsoft Graph you need to have the necessary token with scopes/permissions to access the given resource and the Bearer Auth - its mandatory in Microsoft Graph world. No other workarounds available on this.

Comment: How to solve the problem where I have one logged-in user with the correct token which needs to create an event for a calendar that is only editable by admin account. Getting the admin bearer token needs to be done in the background without the user's knowledge? I use flask_oauthlib package and OAuthRemoteApp.authorize method only redirects me to the login page of the office365 account. I do not want redirection, only one function that returns the correct token passing the admin's credentials.

Comment: A suggestion would be that you can use AAD flow like (Client Credential flow), so with right set of permission the admin can access the other users mailboxes. But make sure it doesn't have any privacy issues associated with it.

Comment: But I do not want admin access to users' mailboxes nor calendars. I want the user (with some action from my app) to produce a flow in which the app with the admin's credentials access the admin's calendar. Users only need to click the button. The user is just someone who starts the flow.